Role of execution.checkpointing.min-pause in case of checkpoint failure
Basic question but just got stumbled on expected behavior of
execution.checkpointing.min-pause in case of checkpoint failure and appreciate your help to correct my understanding
Assuming:

execution.checkpointing.timeout: 1 h
execution.checkpointing.min-pause: 20 m

Flink Version: 1.16.2
Case: Checkpoint failed  due to longer time

Checkpoint starts:10:00AM , unable to finish and failed at 11:00AM
Next checkpoint will trigger 11:20AM or it will immediately trigger
at 11:00AM ??

I was expecting 20m delay after the failure.. is there any other setting??
